# OpenShift 3.11 Running command in Deployment Config

Tags: openshift, minishift

I am attempting to run a command to create a symbolic link when the deployment is run. I have thus added the command: and args: blocks to the YAML. An error is shown about indentation underneath the args block.

[image: minishift/OpenShift 3.11 GUI showing error]

Hovering over the error shows the following:

[image]

How can I correct the YAML?

Comment: FWIW, based on the image, it _looks like_ that theres a bad interpretation starting on like 38. Maybe try removing `>-` on line 37, then move the line 38 content (`172.30.1.1...`) up to line 37 so it would look like `- image: 172.30.1.1...`. See if that fixes the following lines so they're not all blue like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information Will.

Removing the **>-** and moving the image address did correct the blue lines. This didn't resolve the issue however following on from your advice I realised the issue was a rookie **YAML** programming mistake. I was using spaces rather than tabs for indentation. Correcting this and using your suggestion resulted in this

[image]

Comment: Spaces would do it...glad its working now!